# Scrapy POST formdata with a single url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I face a situation that I have to post some data to get information I want. 
Besides,POST information, anything else is the the same. For example,

```
{'data':'cat'}
```

the website will show information about cat.

```
{'data' : 'dog'}
```

show dog's information.

the question is I got millions of data need to be sent.

I knew how to run this spider by single thread. I just want to know is there any way I can run the spider In parallel？

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use multiple threads when you know what threads are?

Comment: Not sure threads are going to help you here.